# Django Redis problem with Docker: InvalidCacheBackendError: No module named 'django.core.cache.backends.redis'

Tags: django, docker, redis-cache

I want to use Redis through docker for the cache but got this error.

```
django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find backend 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache': No module named 'django.core.cache.backends.redis'
```

My cache settings are this.

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
    }
}
```

I took them from Django documentation.

I used this command to start a Redis instance in docker.

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django introduced the Redis backend in version 4.0.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#redis

Make sure the the Django version in the docker container is at least 4.0.

Or if you don't want to upgrade Django, you can use packages such as `django-redis`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from the line `'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'` which do not match the name you've given to the `redis` container in your docker network.

Indeed, the command `docker run --name some-redis -d redis` assigns `some-redis` to the container name, so yo have to refer to your Redis instance with this name in your Python code.

In a nutshell, you have to replace `'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'` by `'LOCATION': 'redis://some-redis:6379'` in the above code.

Comment: service name will resolve to IP address inside the container, right ?  they why you mentioned 127.0.0.1 in the last step again with service name ?

Comment: Indeed, I updated my answer ;)